# Custom Markers on Google Maps. (To be used in Iphone)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am designing a **website that for Iphone** that finds latlong of a certain place and displays it on a google map. Don't worry about LatLongs I have the necessary Details.
I am currently able to use google map by passing a **predefined latlong** to it. My question is how can I place **my custom Markers** over the Map being shown in Iphone.

`<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>`

And I call a function **initialize()** on document ready

```
 function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.902, 74.768);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The google maps API reference has a section about [customizing icons](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Icons).